# Setting the pointer position

Tags: c

I have large data in the file but every time I'm reading only 4096 elements. So, second time when I'm reading I have to update the pointer to 4097th element. How do I do that?

Comment: Way not enough information to answer the question

Comment: How about [fseek](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/fseek.html)

Comment: Is fseek opposite of ftell?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik **No** `ftell` and `fseek` are two different thing. `ftell` returns the current value of the position indicator and `fseek` allows to seek to required position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *p = input;
/* do some code, use p instead of input*/
p = p+4096;
```

Comment: @Vivek "input" I believe is array to store coming data.
And "do some code" means reading those data and storing it in input (using variable "p" as pointer to same memory block)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fread()` or `fscanf()` or `fgetc()` to read from file, it increments the file pointer automatically. You can check that using `ftell()`.

Example:

```
fread(buf, 4096, 1, fp);   // Call 1
fread(buf, 4096, 1, fp);   // Call 2, just after 1st one
```

will read 4096 bytes from file pointed to by `fp`, store it in `buf` and the second time it will start reading from byte# 4097.
You don't need to explicitly increment `fp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ptr++;
```

should do the trick.

The way this works is c implicitly understands it to be the location in memory + the size of the data object pointed to by poitner. In the case of int it would be sizeOf(int). =]